# passing data from JSON to Backbone > Template Page

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

So, I have this from a project I inherited.

- JSON Fields for data.

---

```
    defaults:{
        "coolstuff":{uuid: null},
            "coolStartDate":new Date(),
            "coolEndDate": new Date(),
            "cooldata":'',

            "supercool":'', // I am adding this (trying)
         },
```

---

Some relevant JS from these others as:

```
  offerStart: function() {
     var date = this.get('coolStartDate')
     return (_.isNull(date)) ? new Date() : helper.formatDate(new Date(date)) ;
  },
```

---

Some other data is found and called within the mark-up as a template;

```
<%= cooldata %>
```

I have failed at every attempt at grabbing the 'supercool' data. I have tried different synatax, on page, off page, everything.

I am wondering what I have to do in backbone *(I am new to backbone.js obviously)*

In order to use my new piece of data or data field 'supercool' via JSON and allow it to work as a template in a page.

---

In this particular case; a drop-down menu.

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control filter">
         <option><%= supercool %></option>
         <option><%= supercool %></option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

---

**Update!**

---

Here is my current attempt at my first run with Backbone.js but still failing.

**( 1.)** MODEL. **(models/page.js)**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore', 
    'underscore',  // Page > Model
    'backbone',
    'helpers/helpers',
    'bbvalidation'
], function(_, Backbone, Helpers) {
    var helper = new Helpers();
    var offerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "/loyalty/api/supercoolfile",
        idAttribute: 'uuid',
        url: function() {
            return this.urlRoot + '/coolguys/' + this.get("id"); //
        },
            defaults:{
         "supercool": "", // here
        },
```

**( 2.)** VIEW. **(views/dashboard/page.js)**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore', // Views -- js/views/page.js
  'backbone',
  'vm',
  'text!templates/dashboard/page.html'
],

  template = _.template(<'<p>Name: <%= supercool %> </p>'),

  render: function() {    
      this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
      return this;
          }

      });
  });
```

**( 3. )** PULLING THE DATA INTO TEMPLATE (attempt) **/dashboard/page.html**

```
         <option><%= supercool %></option>
```

Should work, right? They are not for me.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on as I'm not certain how all of your code is connected, but if you have a render function as the below, it should grab 'supercool' for you:

```
template = _.template(<your template here>),

render: function() {    
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
}
```

This is assuming that the first bit of code is from the model passed into your view. The template will pick out the data that it needs.

EDIT:

There's a lot in this for a single post. A collection is not necessary for a Backbone project. What it is for is to hold a collection of models. i.e. You want to store multiple offers, and the way to do that is a collection. A collection will allow you to be able to iterate through each model in your view to render them. Also, you initialize your model as offerModel, but pass OfferModel as the model in your collection. And I don't understand why you've re-written the collection fetch method.

I'm not sure exactly where this is going, but it looks like there a bunch of unnecessary complication.

2nd EDIT:

I created a very basic jsfiddle that shows you how to get this to render, without most of the extraneous information:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmerkes/RdbXH/1/

Comment: Ah man! Thanks a bunch; OK so my first bit of code should be in my Models file, correct? And what should I write in 'view' -- is this what your suggesting I pop into 'view' render? I think this may be my mistake! I'm gonna give it a shot tomorrow when I'm back in the app!

Comment: Yeah, the first bit of code should be inside a Backbone Model object, and you'll need to create a View Backbone object with the above render function. You'll instantiate a view and pass in an instance of the model, and then call the view's render function. I'd look at some sample code as there's a lot of bits and pieces to getting it all to work properly.

Comment: Thanks @EmptyArsenal I am still hitting a wall here; I just updated my question I know if I get this I can start using backbone.js successfully!

Comment: when you mentioned <your template here> you mean filepath of the data output, right? EG. <dashboard/page.html>

Comment: No. Either I put in the html directly inside the template method: `_.template('<p>Name: <%= name %> </p>'` Or, I put the template in index.html `<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template"> ... template html ... </script>` and `_.template($('#myTemplate' ).html())`

Comment: Your right, I am removing the 'Collections' aspect of the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Awesome! And essentially I am replacing 'Me' and 'Batman' your mock data with some jQuery get data?

Comment: Talking to the server is where fetch and save come into play, so jQuery should be unnecessary. fetch is a get request and save is put request.